Suitable TVS diodes
I have a circuit on an old bit of equipment that keeps ending up in our telecoms workshop,my colleague thinks this is from surges, the system has a 12v 5A supply, the circuit has 5v and 3.3v rails, as it's old kit, there is no SMD's. the IC's are even direct soldered to through holes.
I'd like to try TVS diodes, but not sure on how to get right ones, not sure if for eg, I need a 12v for 12 or 5v for 5v, or eg a 15v for 12v so basically a couple voltas higher than the circuits, I also believe I need a TVS on each of the 3 rails, or maybe not on 12v but certainly on  3.3 and 5 ?
Any suggestions? Or is this the wrong forum to bother asking on, I'm happy to ask elsewhere if this is not a valid question.

Your colleague may be right, it might be surges. But who has determined they come from supply lines? Since it is a piece of telecom equipment, it must have some other inputs and outputs than power supplies. So it might not be the supply that breaks the thing itself, it must be how this device is in the system.

You pick one rated a couple of volts above the expected maximum of normal operation, so that it doesn't conduct in normal operation and draw current needlessly.
It also really depends on what your 12V is coming from. If it's a car battery for example, then it will have a higher voltage than 12V when fully charged and these days there are also different chemistries - LiFePO4 will have even higher voltages etc.
Since voltage spike events usually come as very high voltages, the exact value is usually not that important. Somewhere between 15V to 18V would be a good choice.
And in case you suspect that the spikes might as well come from chassis as from the supply, you may want to consider a bidirectional TVS.

I also believe I need a TVS on each of the 3 rails

Only if they are exposed to the outside world somehow (connectors, buttons etc) and you expect that ESD could be the culprit. Older IC families are much more prone to ESD damage than modern ones, where built-in ESD protection is pretty much standard.

ESD is a prime suspect especially if the failing devices are CMOS logic chips that connect to things like front panel switches. Seen it many times especially for devices from 1980s and 90s.

Thanks Lundin,makes sense, I'll play it safe and get some 18v bidirectionals.
